# MySQL - Task Manager - S-Curve - Summarizing tasks

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm bulding a Project Manager System using PHP and MySQL, among other languages, and I'm strugling to query my data in order to create a S-Curve Chart.
In my data base I have the following table named "Tasks"

| ID | Task | Beginning_Date | End_date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent |
| 2 | Task-2 | 2021-12-02 | 2021-12-07 | Completed |
| 3 | Task-3 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-07 | Completed |

To draw the chart, I need to have a row for every day between the minimum date and the maximum date of the Task Table table, even if this exact date does not exist in the task table (example: 2021-12-04 - it is not written on the table, but it happens between 2021-12-01 and 2021-12-07).
And, for every day, I need to count the duration of all the tasks in days that exist before the date and the same for only the completed tasks (I'll try to explain better with an example):

| Day | Days_Tasks | Days_Tasks_Completed | Observation: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 (first day from the Task Table) | 1 | 0 | Counting: Only one day of task-1 |
| 2021-12-02 | 3 | 1 | **Days_Task:** 2 days of task1 + 1 day of task2 **Completed_Taks:** 1 day of Task2 |
| 2021-12-03 | 6 | 3 | **Days_Task:** 3 days of task1 + 2d of task2 + 1d task3 **Completed_Taks:** 2 day of Task2 and 1d task3 (it does not count the days from task1 becouse it is not "Completed" |
| 2021-12-04 | 9 | 5 | **Days_Task:** 4days of task1 plus 3d of task2 plus 2d task3 **Completed_Taks:** 3d of task2 and 2d task3 |
| 2021-12-05 | 12 | 7 | **Days_Task:** 5d of task1 plus 4d of task2 plus 3d task3 **Completed_Taks:** 4d of task2 plus 3d task3 |
| 2021-12-06 | 15 | 9 | **Days_Task:** 6d of task1 plus 5d of task2 plus 4d task3 **Completed_Taks:** 5d of task2 plus 4d task3 |
| 2021-12-07 (last day) | 17 | 11 | **Days_Task:** 6d of task1 plus 6d of task2 plus 5d task3 Completed_Taks: 6d of task2 plus 5d task3 |

Explanation:
The last day (2020-12-07) is the last date that appear on the Task Table. For that day, I'd have do count 17 "Days Task" (6 days for the Task 1 becouse all the 6 days of duration happend before 2020-12-07 + all the days for Task2 + all the day for the duration of task 3)
The same goes for the completed "Days Task" but only counting day of completed tasks - for that reason, not considering Task 1 since it is "Pendent").

I honestly, have no idea how to perform that using MySQL. I tryed a bunch of queries and nothing seemed to work as I wanted.

I was able to get a Table with all the dates using:

```
@i<-1;
SELECT DATE(ADDDATE((SELECT MIN(Beginning_Date) from tasks), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS date FROM `tasks`
HAVING 
@i < DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(End_date) from tasks), (SELECT MIN(Beginning_Date) from tasks )))
```

However, I have no idea how to count the tasks for these dates.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Please update your `Observation:` column as seems to be incorrect. `2020-12-06` Days_Tasks = 15 but Obs: 6 + 5 + 3. Similarly for `2020-12-07` Days_Tasks = 17 but Obs: 6 + 6 + 4. Please add similar explanation for each line of Days_Tasks_Completed

Comment: Hi @nnichols. The webserver is running MySQL 8.0. You are completely right about the mistake. I've already edited the Observation column and add new comment for the Completed tasks

Comment: I think it is still wrong but I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to calculate. Have you had a look at my [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b76572b487ab19913e83e7c882881e7d)? I will try to update my answer with an explanation of why I think your sample data is wrong if I can get to a computer later.

Comment: @nnichols, don't worry. I found my mistake .. Just explaining better, let's take the 2020-12-06 as an example. For this day I have 6 days from task1 (from 2020-12-01 until 2020-12-06), 5 days from Task2 (from 2020-12-02 until 2020-12-06) and 4 days from task3 (from 2020-12-03 until 2020-12-06) - total of 15 days. For the completed_tasks I just filter the completed ones, so, the days from Task1 go away, resulting in 9 days... Your fiddle is right. It 's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please remember to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. If you need further explanation please comment on the answer and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be some errors in your table of desired output. If I understand correctly the following query works but this requires MySQL 8. The first [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) is your example data. The second CTE is a [recursive CTE to provide the date range](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series). Then the query does some aggregation based on the dates and statuses.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE `Tasks` (`ID`, `Task`, `Beginning_Date`, `End_date`, `Status`) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'Task-1', DATE('2021-12-01'), DATE('2021-12-06'), 'Pendent' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Task-2', DATE('2021-12-02'), DATE('2021-12-07'), 'Completed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Task-3', DATE('2021-12-03'), DATE('2021-12-07'), 'Completed'
),
`dates` (`date`) AS
(
  SELECT MIN(`Beginning_Date`) FROM `Tasks`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM `dates`
  WHERE `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= (SELECT MAX(`End_date`) FROM `Tasks`)
)
SELECT
    `d`.`date` AS `Day`,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(LEAST(`d`.`date`, `t`.`End_date`), `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1) AS `Days_Tasks`,
    SUM(IF(`t`.`Status` = 'Completed', DATEDIFF(LEAST(`d`.`date`, `t`.`End_date`), `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1, 0)) AS `Days_Tasks_Completed`
FROM `dates` `d`
INNER JOIN `Tasks` `t` ON `t`.`Beginning_Date` <= `d`.`date`
GROUP BY `d`.`date`
ORDER BY `d`.`date`;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b76572b487ab19913e83e7c882881e7d)

To better understand what is happening we can look at the result of the JOIN for just Task-1

```sql
/* The CTEs are as above but left out for brevity */
SELECT
    `d`.`date` AS `Day`, t.*,
    /*
        we need to add one as MAX Days_Tasks is inclusive
        of Beginning_Date and End_date
    */
    DATEDIFF(`d`.`date`, `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1 AS `Days_Tasks_1`,
    /*
        we need to use the LEAST of d.date and t.End_date so
        we do not continue to count days beyond the t.End_date
    */
    DATEDIFF(LEAST(`d`.`date`, `t`.`End_date`), `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1 AS `Days_Tasks_2`
FROM `dates` `d`
INNER JOIN `Tasks` `t` ON `t`.`Beginning_Date` <= `d`.`date`
WHERE `t`.`ID` = 1
ORDER BY `d`.`date` ASC;
```

which returns -

| Day | ID | Task | Beginning_Date | End_date | Status | Days_Tasks_1 | Days_Tasks_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-12-02 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-12-03 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-12-04 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-12-05 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-12-06 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-12-07 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 7 | 6 |

Days_Tasks_1 looks fine until we get to the final row where it has continued increasing even though Task-1 has ended. To correct this we need to use the [LEAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) of `Day` and `End_date` so we do not continue beyond the End_date of the task. See Days_Tasks_2

Now if we look at the JOIN result for just Day 2021-12-07

```sql
/* CTEs omitted as above */
SELECT
    `d`.`date` AS `Day`, t.*,
    DATEDIFF(LEAST(`d`.`date`, `t`.`End_date`), `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1 AS `Days_Tasks`,
    IF(`t`.`Status` = 'Completed', DATEDIFF(LEAST(`d`.`date`, `t`.`End_date`), `t`.`Beginning_Date`) + 1, 0) AS `Days_Tasks_Completed`
FROM `dates` `d`
INNER JOIN `Tasks` `t` ON `t`.`Beginning_Date` <= `d`.`date`
WHERE `d`.`date` = '2021-12-07'
ORDER BY `t`.`ID` ASC;
```

which returns -

| Day | ID | Task | Beginning_Date | End_date | Status | Days_Tasks | Days_Tasks_Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-07 | 1 | Task-1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-06 | Pendent | 6 | 0 |
| 2021-12-07 | 2 | Task-2 | 2021-12-02 | 2021-12-07 | Completed | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-12-07 | 3 | Task-3 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-07 | Completed | 5 | 5 |

Here you can see the counts as described in `Observation:` column of the example. With the grouping on `Day` and SUM of `Days_Tasks` and `Days_Tasks_Completed` you can see the result desired.

| # Day | Days_Tasks | Days_Tasks_Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-12-02 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-12-03 | 6 | 3 |
| 2021-12-04 | 9 | 5 |
| 2021-12-05 | 12 | 7 |
| 2021-12-06 | 15 | 9 |
| 2021-12-07 | 17 | 11 |